# openDatabase() method throws an exception (SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18)

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, ios4, cordova

openDatabase() method throws an exception (**SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18**) on iPad 4.3 and also on all iOS Simulators 4.x when the database size is specified greater than 5 MB.

Compiling under XCode 4.2 (Mac OS X 10.6.8) using PhoneGap 1.0.0.

Can we circumvent this restriction?

Here is a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>        
        try {
            var db = window.openDatabase("TMA", "1.0", "TMA Mobile Database", 1024 * 1024 * 10);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    </script> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
</head> 
<body> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that throws the exception?

Comment: Jason Dean, updated question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this resource](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch05_id35816678.html#ch05_id35933104) the maximum size imposed by the iOS itself is 5mb. Once it reaches a 5mb size it will ask the user if they want it to grow larger.

I doubt there is any good way around it.

Have you tried creating more than one DB? Perhaps two 5mb DBs would work for you.